Azure Function App using Key Vault with Managed identity not authorised
I have written a function app and at the start of my code I have:
 var credential = new  ManagedIdentityCredential(); 
 var client = new SecretClient(vaultUri, credential);

Within Azure, I have gone to the 'Identity' section of my function app and set status to 'on' for system assigned. I have also gone to the key vault and with 'Access Control (IAM), I have added the managed identity as a Key Vaults Secrets User.
From within my function app if I go to Access Control there, I have Assigned the managed role as a contributor and managed application contributor role.
I have no idea what else I need to set to give access to the key vault from within my app for the managed user.
I also publish the function all as self-contained.
Start of the error in the invocation section of the function app

Result: Failure Exception: Azure.RequestFailedException: Caller is not
authorized to perform action on resource. If role assignments, deny
assignments or role definitions were changed recently, please observe
propagation time. Caller:
appid=61c8be63-9b5d-4c29-80ec-c839a0f0a61c;oid=849fa139-74c5-4adb-9b94-74bc444b68c0;iss=https://sts.windows.net/2f77693b-b7cd-4918-8d8a-d4f28910516f/
Action: 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets/getSecret/action' Resource:
'/subscriptions/fb54f07b-964f-4366-88e2-

Following Ikhtesam Shots from his answer below I have:
In my Program.cs file I have:
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices((context,services) =>
    {
        var vaultUri = new Uri("https://{Key Vault Name Here}.vault.azure.net/"); 
        var credential = new   ManagedIdentityCredential(); 
        var client = new SecretClient(vaultUri, credential); 
        services.AddSingleton(client); 
        services.AddTransient<ISecretService, SecretService>();

then in my function app I have:
public class GetMongoData
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly IMySqlSession _session;
    private readonly IMySqlClaimants _claimants;
    private readonly IMySqlAddresses _addresses;    
    private readonly IMySqlClaims _claims;
    private readonly IMySqlDefendants _defendants;
    private readonly IMySqlDuplicateClaims _duplicateClaims;
    private readonly IMySqlEvidence _evidence;
    private readonly IMySqlStatuses _statuses;
    private readonly ISecretService _secretService;
    private readonly string _sshPath;
    private readonly string _mySqlServerIp;

    public GetMongoData(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IConfiguration 
configuration, IMySqlSession mySqlSession, IMySqlClaimants mySqlClaimants,
                        IMySqlAddresses mySqlAddresses, IMySqlClaims mySqlClaims, IMySqlDefendants defendants, IMySqlDuplicateClaims mySqlDuplicateClaims,
                        IMySqlEvidence mySqlEvidence, IMySqlStatuses mySqlStatuses, ISecretService secretService)
    {

        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<GetMongoData>();
        _session = mySqlSession;
        _secretService = secretService;
        _claimants = mySqlClaimants;
        _addresses = mySqlAddresses;
        _claims = mySqlClaims;
        _defendants = defendants;
        _duplicateClaims = mySqlDuplicateClaims;
        _evidence = mySqlEvidence;
        _statuses = mySqlStatuses;
        _mySqlServerIp = _secretService.GetSecret("MySqlServerIp");
        _defendants = defendants;
        
       
    }

[Function("RetrieveMongoData")]
public void Run([TimerTrigger("0 0 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer)
{ //function set to run every hour.
    _logger.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
    try
    {
        var server = _mySqlServerIp;
        var sshUserName = "forge";
        var sshPassword = "";



Have you check in application insight for any error or exception?

Did you try with Key Vault Secrets Officer role?

@IkhtesamAfrin I see the error in the invocations log. I'll update the question with the start of the error, as it's very long.

@IkhtesamAfrin No I didn't interesting though, when I did that it also listed my function app as somethin that can have that role assigned. So I've assigned both the function app and the maanged user that role. I'll seee what happens.

You need to grant the role to function app's managed identity correctly. Check my solution @bilpor

Can you share your complete function code @bilpor

@IkhtesamAfrin I have added mre code


I have enabled the managed identity in function app and then granted Key Vault Secrets Officer RBAC role by navigating to Key vault instance -> Access Control (IAM) -> Add role assignment as shown below.



I am using below code in function app to fetch the secret value.

using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;

namespace FunctionApp6
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("GetSecret")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            try
            {
                string keyVaultUrl = "https://{keyvaultName}.vault.azure.net/";

                var credential = new ManagedIdentityCredential();
                var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(keyVaultUrl), credential);

                string secretName = "testSecret"; 
                KeyVaultSecret secret = await client.GetSecretAsync(secretName);
                string secretValue = secret.Value;

                log.LogInformation($"Fetched Secret Value: {secretValue}");

                return new OkObjectResult($"Secret fetched successfully. Check logs for the value.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.LogError($"Error fetching secret: {ex.Message}");
                return new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
            }
        }
    }
}


Got the secret value successfully.


If you intent to read the secret content then Key Vaults Secrets User role should do. Please verify if you have assigned the role correctly as I did.
I have created an isolated timer trigger function and have added below given code in program.cs file which worked successfully for me.
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
    {
        var vaultUri = new Uri("https://afreeenKv.vault.azure.net/");
        var credential = new ManagedIdentityCredential();
        var client = new SecretClient(vaultUri, credential);
        services.AddSingleton(client);
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();



am using a timer trigger, so when I go to 'code + test', I dont quite get the same as you. I'll add my screen shot's to the question.

Can you share your function code

@bilpor modified my answer please check. Are you still getting permission error or any other error?

I have added role assignment as you suggested. The only difference THhat I can see  from my code to your example is that I'm using a timer trigger. It still errors but the message now does not really give any help. Executing 'Functions.RetrieveMongoData' (Reason='Timer fired at 2024-12-19T11:00:00.0007706+00:00', Id=159505f2-6a06-4cdb-b2d9-dbf5e97cc334)

@bilpor I also have created a timer trigger function and having same code alike you in program.cs file. Check in application insight to get detailed error. You might not get all the error information in invocation log

Not giving anymore info via app insights

You must be getting some error or info as you only have shared Executing Functions.RetrieveMongoData which means function is executing

From Visual Studio if I set credential to DefaultAzureCredential then in debug mode it works. If I set it to ManagedIdentityCredential then I receive a time out error.

managed identity doesn't works locally, it will work in azure only
